# Bundle JRE with PDE headless build

Tags: eclipse, build, pde

I have the build script (PDE Headless build) for building the RCP application. And it work's as expected. I have 2 tasks which am not able to close it.

1. Am trying to bundle the JRE along with my RCP application, and i followed the steps provided in this [URL](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_rootfiles.htm). Still am not able to bundle the JRE with my built application. I tried something like this in my build.properties file:
   root=absolute:c:/java/jre. Where - c:/java/jre is the root directory where my jre resides. 
   has anyone faced this problem?
2. My application uses DB2 database for saving/reading the data. Is it possible to bundle my database along with my application using PDE headless build? If so, please throw some light on this topic too. Am using DB2-ExpressC latest version

Thanks

Comment: Is this a `build.properties` for a feature? `root` only works in features

Comment: No, this is for a product build (which is dependent on features). Is there any way to bundle JRE with the product?

Comment: A product build is fine, but the build.properties must be one of the features included in the build.

Comment: I added  "root=absolute:c:/java/jre" in the build.properties file of my main feature and it worked. Thanks. And do you have suggstions for the second point in my post?