# Include JRE by using Eclipse Product Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm using Eclipse Mars(4.5.2) and already create a plugin project. I'm using "Eclipse product export wizard" to export the product to multiple platforms. So it's working now.

please help me to include JRE folder when i export the product to multiple platforms.

I have to try add some line below in to build.properties but it still not work

```
    root.linux.gtk.x86=jre_linux_86/
root.linux.gtk.x86.permissions.755=jre_linux_86/
root.win32.win32.x86=jre_win_32/
```

Comment: 'root' only works in the build.properties for a Feature - so are you using a feature?

Comment: are you clicking this box `Bundle JRE for this environment with the product`?
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#product_configuration

Comment: @greg-449: No, I'm using Eclipse Product Configuration to export.

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan: Yes, But it's not working.

Comment: Its that only when you run PDE build. As greg said you can check if you have features based product.
 Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426436/bundle-jre-with-pde-headless-build

Comment: i'm using the "Bundle JRE for this environment with the product" option, and still no export of the JRE! Any ideas?